# Font Awesome not working in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, font-awesome

I first loaded reference to css file in  section of seattle.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Then i simply inserted

```
<i class="fa fa-television">television</i>
```

When i load the home page i only see the text television but not font?

Am i doing something wrong. what else needs to be done to render font awesome in SharePoint page?

I tried Following in simple html i created in notepad it works:

```
<html>


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>


<body>
<i class="fa fa-television"></i>
television


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"> to the head

Comment: you mean top of the html page(seattle.html) in sharepoint. tried in chrome it is not working there either.

Comment: Did add it no change.

Comment: If you host that same simple page on the SharePoint server, is it still rendering correctly? I wonder if this isn't a symptom of a problem somewhere else...

Comment: Thats Crazy, if i load the simple html in Html Forms Webpart , it renders correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the fa prefix:

```
<i class"fa fa-television"></i> television
```

Comment: Tried that, it didnt work either.

Comment: do you have any console errors?

Comment: Nothing related to Font awesome. I see some scripts error for a javascipt loaded on the page.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the element you're using for the icon would need to be empty:

`<i class="fa fa-television"></i> television`

That's the case with all the examples, and how I've used it on a couple of sites.

Comment: I just updated the element, no results.